# Android MediaPlayer getCurrentPosition() returning wrong values

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a service where I have created a `MediaPlayer` Object. I then bind to the service to get info about the media being played like current seek position. For testing purpose, created a button which invokes `getCurrentPosition`() method of the `MediaPlayer`. However each time it returns some random value. (I am calling `getCurrentPosition` only after the start() is called and the media is playing). `getDuration`() is returning correct duration of the song.

```
public class SongPlayService extends Service {

    private static final String SERVICE_INTENT_KEY = "com.example.strehan.galleryapp.SERVICE_INTENT_KEY";

    private SongPlayThread mSongPlayThread;
    private String mSongData;
    private SongPlayServiceHandler mHandler;
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

    public class SongPlayServiceBinder extends Binder {

        public  SongPlayService getSongPlayService() {
            return SongPlayService.this;
        }
    }

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d("SongPlayService", "onCreate()");
        mHandler = new SongPlayServiceHandler();
        mSongPlayThread = new SongPlayThread("SongPlay Thread", mHandler, getApplicationContext());
        mSongPlayThread.start();
        mSongPlayThread.initHandler(mSongPlayThread.getLooper());
        mMediaPlayer = mSongPlayThread.createMediaPlayer();
    }

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("SongPlayService", "onBind()");
        return  new SongPlayServiceBinder();
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("SongPlayService", "onStartCommand()");
        mSongData  = intent.getStringExtra(SERVICE_INTENT_KEY);
        Log.d("SongPlayService", "Song data rcvd at service: " + mSongData);
        if (mSongData != null) {
            mSongPlayThread.resetMediaPlayer();
            mSongPlayThread.prepareSong(mSongData);
            playSong();
        }
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    public int getSeekInfo() {
        return mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    }
}


public class SongPlayThread extends HandlerThread implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener,
        MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {


    private Handler mRequestHandler;
    private Handler mResponseHandler;
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    private Context mContext;

    public void initHandler(Looper looper) {

        mRequestHandler = new Handler(looper) {

            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                switch (msg.what) {
                    case MSG_PREPARE_PLAYER:
                        Log.d("SongPlayThread", "Prepare song recvd: Song data:" + msg.obj);
                        Log.d("SongPlayThread", "Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        processPrepareMsg(msg.obj.toString());
                        break;

                    case  MSG_PLAY_SONG:
                        Log.d("SongPlayThread", "Play Song msg rcvd");
                        processPlayMsg();
                        break;
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private void processPlayMsg() {
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    }

    private void processPrepareMsg(String path) {
        try {

            Log.d("SongPlayThread", "Registering listeners: Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);

            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(mContext, uri);
            mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
                   ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

> ```
>   02-07 15:55:00.380    7379-7379/ D/SongPlayFragment﹕ Seek: 3275
>         02-07 15:55:00.825    7379-7379/ D/SongPlayFragment﹕ Seek Button pressed
>         02-07 15:55:00.825    7379-7379/ D/SongPlayFragment﹕ Service connected
>         02-07 15:55:00.826    7379-7379/ D/SongPlayFragment﹕ Seek: 3723
>         02-07 15:55:01.000    7379-7379/ D/SongPlayFragment﹕ Seek Button pressed
>         02-07 15:55:01.000    7379-7379/ D/SongPlayFragment﹕ Service connected
>         02-07 15:55:01.001    7379-7379/ D/SongPlayFragment﹕ Seek: 3898
>         02-07 15:55:01.194    7379-7379/ D/SongPlayFragment﹕ Seek Button pressed
>         02-07 15:55:01.194    7379-7379/ D/SongPlayFragment﹕ Service connected
>         02-07 15:55:01.196    7379-7379/ D/SongPlayFragment﹕ Seek: 4093
>         02-07 15:55:01.334    7379-7379/ D/SongPlayFragment﹕ Seek Button pressed
>         02-07 15:55:01.334    7379-7379/ D/SongPlayFragment﹕ Service connected
>         02-07 15:55:01.335    7379-7379/ D/SongPlayFragment﹕ Seek: 131
>         02-07 15:55:01.494    7379-7379/ D/SongPlayFragment﹕ Seek Button pressed
>         02-07 15:55:01.494    7379-7379/ D/SongPlayFragment﹕ Service connected
>         02-07 15:55:01.497    7379-7379/ D/SongPlayFragment﹕ Seek: 292
>         02-07 15:55:01.672    7379-7379/ D/SongPlayFragment﹕ Seek Button pressed
>         02-07 15:55:01.672    7379-7379/ D/SongPlayFragment﹕ Service connected
>         02-07 15:55:01.674    7379-7379/ D/SongPlayFragment﹕ Seek: 470
> ```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: check this.....https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2559
be sure your MP3's are 44100 Hz.

Comment: @KenWolf posted the code

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the `MediaPlayer` has an old issue when sometimes `currentPosition` returns wrong values [(1)](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36907697), [(2)](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36921987)

So here is workaround how to possibly handle it:

```
fun runPlayerDurationUpdate(mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer) {
    playerCurrentDuration.value = 0

    durationJob?.cancel()
    durationJob = viewModelScope.launch {
        while (mediaPlayer.currentPosition != mediaPlayer.duration) {
            val progress = mediaPlayer.currentPosition * 100 / mediaPlayer.duration
            if (progress < playerCurrentDuration.value!!) {
                continue
            } else {
                delay(PLAYER_DELAY)
                playerCurrentDuration.value = progress
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where

```
 private const val PLAYER_DELAY = 50L 
 private val playerCurrentDuration = MutableLiveData(0)
```